# How to show a canvas text when i click an UI button on Android

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to show a text when i click on a ui button but i don't know how to implement this. On PC platform I have a collider per object and when the player stay and click the E button, a canvas text appear on screen, but i don't know how to do this on Android. I want something like Resident Evil old style action button, opening doors and getting object description. How could i do this?

**The Script**

```
public class readingNote : MonoBehaviour {


    public AudioSource audio;
    public AudioClip collectSound;
    public  bool playerNextToKey = false;
    bool hasCollided = false;
    public GameObject pic;
    public GameObject text;
    public GameObject notePad;
    private Collider other;


//  void Start () {
//      pic.SetActive(false);
//      text.SetActive (false);
//
//  }


    public Button yourButton;

    void Start()
    {
        pic.SetActive(false);
        text.SetActive (false);
        Button btn = yourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
      //can't text.SetActive(true); because when i get out the scene, text is showing up (I use the same button to open doors and get text description).
    }

    void OnTriggerStay ( Collider other) {


        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            //if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) {
                text.SetActive (true);
                pic.SetActive(true);

                AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(collectSound, transform.position);
            //} 



        }
    }


    void  OnTriggerExit ( Collider other  )
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            //enter = false;
            //print("close");
            playerNextToKey = false;
            hasCollided = false;
            pic.SetActive(false);
            text.SetActive (false);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you said in your comments you need a system that shows specific info in specific trigger. you can do it in many different ways. right now using something like a dictionary is in my mind.
first of define triggers and a variable in class of your character. I write it as psudo code so it may need some changes.

```
public GameObject   canvasText; //assign ui text game object in editor

string mystring;

    void start()
{
Dictionary<string, string> mydic =  new Dictionary<string, string>();
mydic.add("x1","open the door");
mydic.add("x2","pic up the pistol")
}

void onTriggerEnter(collider other)
{
mystring=mydic[other.name];
}

void onTriggerExit(collider other)
{
mystring="";
canvasText.getcomponent<Text>().text="";
}

    public void UIbutton()// assign this function to function of your button in editor
    {
canvasText.getcomponent<Text>().text=mystring;
    vanvasText.setActive(true);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that and it works, the thing is, the UI button is an action button that open doors and read texts, so when i go out the scene, the text is showing up too.

Comment: @can you explain more? what is you problem exactly?

Comment: My game is like Resident Evil old style and when i'm close to an object and press UI button, a description of that object appear on screen. Everything is fine at this point, but if i use your solution, the UI description of all obejcts of scene are showing on screen when i change scene because i am using the same button for all (change scene and get object descriptions).

Comment: @Jose now you question is clear. there are lot of approaches that you can handle your problem. ill try editing my answer